# str_replace with variable as needle not working what do I do wrong

Tags: php, str-replace

I try to index a directory for the example it looks like `files/subdir/file.txt` only one subdir and file. I store the first directory in `$dir = "files/"` then want to the directory of a file minus the value in $dir I tried it with `$curdir = str_replace( $dir, '', $file->getPath() )` but it doesn't work when I try it with `$curdir = str_replace( 'files/', '', $file->getPath() )` it does work, why is this what am I missing?

To clearify

```
<?php
$dir = 'files/';
$files = new ArrayObject();
$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator,RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if( $file->getFilename()[0] == '.' ){ continue; }

    $curdir = str_replace( $dir, '', $file->getPath() );
    $files[$curdir][] = $file;

}
print_r($files);
```

It keeps returning this

```
ArrayObject Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [files/subdir] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SplFileInfo Object
                        (
                            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => files\subdir\file.txt
                            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => file.txt
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

But what I want it to return is the following

```
ArrayObject Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [subdir] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SplFileInfo Object
                        (
                            [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => files/subdir\file.txt
                            [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => file.txt
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

## Solution:

Andrew's sugestion to use `FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS` solved the problem for me.

```
$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS);
```

Comment: you can set a `FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` flag or `4096` to skip dot btw

Comment: btw the problem might be spl retrurning \, but you are replacing with /, so the replacement didnt match and thus not happened

Comment: you can also set `FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS` so forward slash is always used regardless of system default

Comment: @Andrew Thanks changing `$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS);` helped me it solved the problem

Comment: You are welcome :) I will put into answer so it can be marked as completed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that SPL is returning `\` in the file path depending on system default, so setting

```
FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS
```

set make SPL always return `\` for clearing the uncertainty; and the replacement is `/` instead of `\` will might not search the match when replacing the string. Thats also what I got many troubles in the first place :)